# Dask concatenate high memory use

Tags: python, dask

I'm trying to use dask to calculate summaries of data stored in a dataset split between about 1,000 parquet files. Each file is between 1Mb - 10Mb. When i convert a series into an array and compute `max` on that array, it works great. However, when I try and `concatenate` two arrays, I quickly run out of memory:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.array as da

data = dd.read_parquet('../data/*.parquet')
field_1 = data['field_1'].to_dask_array()
field_2 = data['field_2'].to_dask_array()
both_fields = da.concatenate((field_1, field_2))
result = da.max(both_fields).compute()
```

I've tried using `Client`, but this is very slow and gives a lot of warnings about garbage collection taking too much CPU time. However, it does seem to run without running out of memory.

I'm new to dask, so perhaps I've misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no specific reason for using arrays, then this might work better:

```py
both_fields = dd.concat([ddf['field_1'], ddf['field_2']], axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This seems to do the same thing, very quickly runs out of memory...